# Brownian Motion independent increment computation

Tags: brownian-motion

One can rather easily show that $E\left[\sum\limits_{i = 0}^{i = n - 1}W_{t_i}(W_{t_{i + 1}} - W_{t_i})\right] = -T + W_T^2$.

What I'm confused about is why we can't simply say that for each $i$, $W_{t_{i}}$ is independent of $(W_{t_{i + 1}} - W_{t_i})$, so that upon interchanging sums and expectations, and using independence we have $E\left[\sum\limits_{i = 0}^{i = n - 1}W_{t_i}(W_{t_{i + 1}} - W_{t_i})\right] = \sum\limits_{i = 0}^{i = n - 1}E\left[W_{t_{i}}\right]E\left[W_{t_{i + 1}} - W_{t_i}\right] = 0$?

In this problem, we have naturally partitioned an interval as $0 = t_{0} < t_{1} < ... < t_{n} = T$, and $W_{t}$ is a Brownian motion.

Comment: Question closed. Thanks Ian!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error: you find that the expectation is $-T+E[W_T^2]=-T+T=0$. That is, your observation is correct. We usually view this as arising from the fact that in the Ito convention, $\int_0^t W_s dW_s$ is a martingale. (So are the integrals of "most" functions against $W_t$.)

Comment: Oh my goodness, thanks so much. I realize what I've done wrong. I'm not taking an expectation at all. As the comment above suggests, I should not have a random variable in an expectation at all. Thanks!

Comment: @user7348 If this answered your question, you should click the check mark next to it in order to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Look here (it is in German, but you can [translate](http://translate.google.com) the text):
[Stochastic integration](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastische_Integration)

Note that there is set $B_i$ instead of $W_i$